# Problema para acceder a elementos de un documento: mongoose

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

Quiero hacer una verificación de contraseña usando express y mongoose.

Todo bien hasta la parte donde reviso la contraseña, simplemente no puedo acceder a ese valor de mi documento.

Esta es mi función:

```
function iniciar_sesion(req, res)
{
  let usu = new Usuario({
    usuario : req.body.usuario,
    password : req.body.password
  })

  Usuario.findOne( {usu_nombre: usu.usuario}, (err, user) => {

    // Comprobar si hay errores
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})

    // Comprobar si el usuario existe
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send({message: `No existe el usuario `})

    // Comprobar si la contraseña es correcta

    console.log(user._id) // marca su valor
    console.log(user.usu_contrasenia) // marca undefined
    console.log(user.usu_nombre) // marca undefined
    console.log(user)

    if (user.usu_contrasenia != usu.password)
      return res.status(400).send({message: 'Contraseña incorrecta'})

    // Genero token
    res.status(200).send(user)

  })

}
```

Sin embargo, cuando hago el console.log(user) imprime todo el documento:

```
{ _id: 586151481787e016382ee4b2,
  usu_nombre: 'John Doe',
  usu_contrasenia: '123' }
```

No debería poder acceder haciendo: **user.usu_contrasenia** ????????

Lo curioso es que el _id sí me lo imprime y sí corresponde con el de la DB.

¿Alguna ayuda?

**Nota:**
Por ahora estoy manejando sin encriptar la contraseña, primero quería hacer este test así pero no me sale o.O

Comment: trata de acceder a ellos de esta manera `console.log(user["usu_nombre"]);`

Comment: @HectorSeguro gracias por tu sugerencia. Me marca "undefined". Lo que me llama la atención es que si coloco console.log(user._id) sí me imprime el valor o.O

Comment: trata con esto `for(var s in user){console.log(s);}` y a ver que te sale.

Comment: Vi un rayo de luz de esperanza al leer tu idea. Imprime todas las propiedades y métodos del objeto, e incluye los atributos usuario y password (wtf?????) no sé por qué se llaman así, sin embargo al querer acceder a ellos usando user.usuario me sigue marcando undefined D: x_X

Comment: @HectorSeguro ya quedó :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución. Sin las sugerencias de @HectorSeguro no lo hubiera logrado.

Lo que pasa es que intentaba acceder a esos valores como un atributo, sin embargo inspeccionando todos los valores del objeto users con el código que sugirió Hector (for(var s in user){console.log(s);}), encontré el método _doc el cual devuelve el documento como tal.

```
user._doc
```

Entonces puedo acceder a los elementos de la siguiente forma:

```
user._doc.usu_usuario
user._doc.usu_contrasenia
```

Entonces mi código queda:

```
'use strict'

const Usuario = require('../models/usuario.js')


function iniciar_sesion(req, res)
{
  let usu = new Usuario({
    usuario : req.body.usuario,
    password : req.body.password
  })

  Usuario.findOne( {usu_nombre: usu.usuario}, (err, user) => {

    // Comprobar si hay errores
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: `Error al realizar la petición: ${err}`})

    // Comprobar si el usuario existe
    if (!user) return res.status(404).send({message: `No existe el usuario `})

    console.log(user._doc.usu_usuario)
    console.log(user._doc.usu_contrasenia)

    if (user._doc.usu_contrasenia != usu.password)
      return res.status(400).send({message: 'Contraseña incorrecta'})

    // Genero token
    res.status(200).send(user)

  })

}

module.exports = ({
  iniciar_sesion
})
```

Muchas gracias Hector de nuevo :')